# Can someone tell me why this query isn't working please?

Tags: mysql, boolean-logic

Can someone tell me why this query isn’t working please?

```
$result = $connect->query( “SELECT * 
                            FROM DBdata 
                            WHERE catc !=‘121’ 
                            AND description LIKE ‘%$strm%’ 
                            OR ttl LIKE ‘%$strm%’ 
                            AND active = 1” );
```

THE PROBLEM - It IS LISTING ‘catc’ that = 121

I want the result it is giving, but don't want the catc items that equal 121

Thanks!

Comment: Use brackets when using `AND` and `OR` at the same time, always.

Comment: You can't use curly quotes as string delimiters in PHP or MySQL.

Comment: This `“` and this `”` and these `‘’` are INVALID. Dont use a word processor to code with, use a code editor

Answer (score 2):

Your `OR` is likely what's messing things up.

```
SELECT * FROM HWpix
    WHERE catc !='121'
    AND 
      (description LIKE '%$strm%'
       OR ttl LIKE '%$strm%')
    AND active = 1
```

Comment: THANK YOU ceejayoz!! It is working.